# Not able to Insert image in database when form has enctype="multipart/form-data

Tags: java, servlets

I am facing issue inserting images in my database while using form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. I have tried using the `Part` class but that only return the name of the image, whereas I want the absolute path of the image. I have also tried using the below code

```
try {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("txtPrdModel")){
                String ProductModel = item.getString();  
            }

            // ... (do your job here)
        } else {
            // Process form file field (input type="file").
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getString());
            InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();
            // ... (do your job here)
        }
    }
```

This code gets the `fieldName` but `getString` doesn't return any value.
I need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and need the absolute path of the file I am trying to upload.

I am using netbeans 8.0.2 and servlet version is 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, the absolute path of the file isn't sent as part of the file name. You can only know the current name of the file that is uploaded to the server, so it's futile trying to obtain the absolute path that the file has on the client.

Once you have the file name and its binary data, use this info to store it in your specific path for files, in database or in another data source you're using.

Comment: Is there any other way I can obtain the absolute path of the file .Since my insert stored procedure is written in such a way that it requires the complete path of the image to process.

Comment: @user_19240589 you should set the absolute path from the server, not from the client. Again: **you cannot obtain the absolute path from the client**. I would suggest to redesign the stored procedure.